# Porting Chrome extension to Firefox : equivalent to chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to port Chrome extension to Firefox and I would like to know what's the equivalent to `chrome.storage.local.set` and `chrome.storage.local.get` in Firefox add on sdk. I think, it's `simple-storage`.

Here is my code :

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'tokenFU': token});

[...]

chrome.storage.local.get('tokenFU',function(result){
                    token=result.tokenFU;
                    if(token && token != 'undefined'){
                        hideLog();
                    }
                    else 
                    showLog();
});
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes exactly, it is [simple-storage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-storage.html). You can use it like this :

```
const storage = require("sdk/simple-storage").storage;

storage.tokenFu = token;
```